# Actualizar posición marker mapBox vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

Estoy realizando un mapa en donde pinto 2 marcadores, pero necesito que se actualicen(ubicación) cada cierto tiempo por lo cual uso setInterval().

Muestro un ejemplo de código

```
 <template>
  <div id="mapContainer" class="basemap"></div>
</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import dataJson from '../api/data'

export default {
  name: 'BaseMap',
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken:
        'key',
       map: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
       container: 'mapContainer',
       style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
       center: [-89.223522, 13.714624],
       zoom: 10
     })
  },

  created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateLocation(), 60000)
  },

  methods: {
    updateLocation() {

      // data api
      dataJson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
        // create a DOM element for the marker
        var el = document.createElement('div')
        el.className = 'marker'
        el.style.backgroundImage = marker.properties.iconUrl
        let url = marker.properties.iconUrl
        el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px'
        el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px'

        // add marker to map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(this.map)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.basemap {
  height: 65vh;
  position: absolute;

  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

El mapa se dibuja pero los marcadores no, en la consola  me muestra el siguiente error Cannot **read property 'map' of undefined** en esta linea **new mapboxgl.Marker(el)**

A la espera de su  valiosa ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: dos cosas.. esa key no es real no? y otra, porque el mapa no esta en data entonces, y en el mounted lo creas....???

Comment: es una key de prueba. trate de poner map en el data pero cuando accedo desde el mounted o created no me lo reconoce, si lo pinto en consola si me pinta el objeto pero cuando lo utilizo para agregarle el marker me da error

Comment: y en el data? no lo guardas ahi?

Comment: lo probe en el data, pero al ponerlo ahi me tira error al momento de agregar los iconos al mapa .addTo(this.map) el error me dice que mapContainer esta indefinido

Comment: Y como le pasate el container una vez generado? Es por ahi por donde lo tenes que hacer funcionar

Comment: primero declare map: ' ' y luego en el created creaba el objeto haciendo uso de este, y luego dentro del metodo updateLocation() para pintar los marcadores utilizaba la variable que declare en el data map

Comment: Crea el objeto en el mounted... y ahi ya no deberia ser undefined...

Comment: pero al crearlo ahi como hago para luego utilizarlo dentro de mi método que estará actualizando las posiciones de los marcadores, porque necesito utilizar este objeto para dibujar los marker?

Comment: si lo pones en el data, esta en todos lados... lo usas como this.mapa... eso lo probaste?

Comment: si correcto lo se, de hecho fue lo primero que hice pero cuando lo hago asi no me muestra los marcadores. Edite el código para que le des un vistazo

Comment: La variable map no esta definido, ya que lo primero que haces es crear la función del actualizado del marcado y después en el mounted crea la instancia donde se almacena el mapa, en orden de ejecución de vue es primero create y después mounted.

Comment: Cual seria el enfoque correcto? porque si paso la creacion del mapa al created antes del setInterval tampoco funciona

Comment: puede validar si la variable map es nula, asignar a la variable map en el data que sea igual a null, y cuando pase a la función de marcados verificas si this.map != null, entonces sabrás si el mapa se ha creado.

Comment: pero con eso no resolvería el problema, lo único que consigo es saber que el mapa esta nulo, pero como hago para que cargue el mapa y los marcadores correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `beforeMount()` en vez del `create()` y poner hay la función de la creación del mapa

```
beforeMount(){
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'mapContainer',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-89.223522, 13.714624],
    zoom: 10
    })     
},
```

para luego usar en el mounted la actualización del marcador

```
mounted(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateLocation(), 60000)
}
```

ya en la función `this.updateLocation()` puedes validar si se creo el mapa en la variable map

```
updateLocation() {
    if (this.map != null){
        // data api
        dataJson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
        // create a DOM element for the marker
        var el = document.createElement('div')
        el.className = 'marker'
        el.style.backgroundImage = marker.properties.iconUrl
        let url = marker.properties.iconUrl
        el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px'
        el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px'

        // add marker to map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .addTo(this.map)
        })
    }
}
```

Así primero creas el mapa y luego se realizara la carga de los marcadores.

Comment: probe y me marca el siguiente error beforeMount hook: "Error: Container 'mapContainer' not found." imagino que es porque aun no se a cargado el dom entonces no encuentra el div para crear el mapa